# Gradle dsl method not found 'min()'

Tags: java, android, gradle

I've got a problem with my gradle.
I knew about update and chcecked every topic with it but i ddnt find anything about gradle dsl method not found 'min()' 
I've got a command in my gradle build type debug min 'proguard-debug.pro'
And i know how to update it

```
debug {
       versionNameSuffix "-deb"
       minifyEnabled false
       min 'proguard-debug.pro'
       zipAlignEnabled true
       signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
       }
```

Comment: Code or didn't happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure where you got the command `min` from but here's how you can specify a proguard file:

```
minifyEnabled true
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

Comment: i added some code. Its in build type

Comment: @Kamil so does my suggestion not work?

Comment: Worked , sorz for problem